# XHTML/CSS issue IE displaying extra characters

Tags: css, internet-explorer, rendering

I have a problem with a clients webpage, you can check it out using the link below where you will see that underneath the 'drinks' option an extra 'ks' appears, however it only repeats the last two characters of the 'drinks' option in IE6 not Firefox or Webkit

http://www.villagiorestaurant.co.uk/drinks-menu.html

Any help would be appreciated.. It's driving me nuts as I can't see what the problem could be!

Comment: Only ie6 or? Can´t see any extra 'ks' in ie8 or ie8-in-ie7-mode.

Comment: Yes just IE6 version 6.0.3790.0, thanks for the correction!

Comment: I can reproduce this in IE6. I note that if you double-click on the extra 'ks' it highlights the "Drinks" in Soft Drinks so looks like a rendering bug. Good luck!

Comment: Well, in that case it´s like bobince says, it´s the duplicate content bug.

Comment: Yep bobince is correct and the position:relative fix sorted it for me.

Answer (score 4):

Ah, the duplicated text content bug, one of the very weirdest IE6 has to offer.

It happens when the right edge of a float abuts the right edge of its parent, for reasons nobody understands. [This post](http://www.positioniseverything.net/explorer/dup-characters.html) at PIE attributes it to comments and other hidden elements, but it seems to happen without that for me.

Fix: put a `margin-right: -3px` on the last float (Soft drinks), or give the floating links `position: relative`.

Comment: Thank you, that sorted it!

I put a position:relative on the options class, the duplicated text has gone and I still have hair left!

Comment: @Ian, mark this as the answer then.  I came here thinking you still needed help.  If you mark it as answer, then I can see on the front page that your issue has been resolved.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Removing 
display:block;

from div.options a

seems to remove the problem too.